# How to display the values from a map on a react web app (javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping, jsx

I am new to JavaScript. I have a map in which I store 3 values to each key. The size of the map is variable and a new key:values pair is added every time a new item is published on the app.

I would like to display the current contents of the map on the web page (ideally a table format but for now I just want to see them printed there before I worry about that). All my searches are obstructed by people talking about google maps.

I have found ways to solve this when using an array but I like the structure of the map.

I initialize an empty map:

```
const productMap = new Map();
```

New items are added to the site and the map expanded:

```
    handleSubmit = async () => {
    const { cost, itemName, quantity } = this.state;

    let result = await this.ItemManager.methods.createItem(itemName, cost, quantity).send({ from: this.accounts[0] });
    const index = result.events.ProductStep.returnValues._productIndex;

    productMap.set(index, {itemName: itemName, cost: cost, quantity: quantity}); **// This is where map values are added. 1 key (index) has 3 values (itemName, cost and quantity)**

    console.log(productMap)
    
    alert("Send "+cost+" Wei to "+result.events.ProductStep.returnValues._address);
  };
```

This function prints to the console exactly how I want, but I am not sure how to get this into the JSX (I think that's the right term?) part.

```
    printValues = () => {
    for(let [key, value] of productMap){
      console.log(value.itemName +':'+ value.cost +':'+ value.quantity) **//This logs 'Item Name' : 'cost' : 'quantity' in a separate row for each key- this is what I ideally want but displayed on the web page**

      return(
        <div>{value.itemName} {value.cost} {value.quantity}</div>
        )
    }
   }
```

I have tried many variations to get this to show up on the web page, but nothing has worked so far.

```
 return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className='App-header' ><img className='App-logo' src={mylogo} alt="logo"/></header>
        <h1>Simply Payment/Supply Chain Example!</h1>
        <h2>Products for sale:</h2>

        {this.printValues} **//I imagine it being something along these lines where the
 //function produces the desired values and they are displayed on the web page.**
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate the same map on JSX and print your values like how you are doing on `console.log`. Since it is a for loop you have to store the items in some variable and use them in JSX. You can update your `printValues()` method like this.

```
printValues = () => {
  let el = [];
  for (let [key, value] of productMap) {
    console.log(value.itemName + ":" + value.cost + ":" + value.quantity); //This logs 'Item Name' : 'cost' : 'quantity' in a separate row for each key- this is what I ideally want but displayed on the web page**
    el.push(value.itemName + ":" + value.cost + ":" + value.quantity);
  }
  return <div>{el}</div>;
};
```

I have attached the sandbox by using both a map and my style of using an array of objects in state. You can check it.

[image: Edit delicate-pond-jqjg15]

Comment: @millbird, If that code solves your problem, you can accept the answer.

Comment: I accepted as this got me very close to the answer. I wasn't able to get it to work exactly as you showed but it got me very close to what I want. Is it possible to access the state the same way you showed without useState (I got errors when using it)? Right now I am able to get what I want but only for 1 of the variables in state. Here is my code if it will help the answer: https://github.com/NicMilli/SupplyChain

Comment: Are you trying to render `ProductsTable`? 
You are updating the state with variables and using it. If you wanna pass those variables to the child component you can do it by passing them as params like `<ProductsTable  productEvents={YourStateVariable} />`. 
It would be great if you share the error that you are getting while accessing the state.

Comment: "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem."

Comment: Sorry that is a very long error but no matter where I place the statement I get that error. I have managed to solve it for the most part (tho im sure my code is very messy). I started learning js/react as part of a blockchain development course and am learning fast that I will benefit greatly from a react course as well. Thank you for the help!